# Differentiation problem: Finding $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> Let $$f(x) = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{x + \dots}}}}} \,.$$ If $f(a) = 4$, then find $f'(a)$.

For this question, I really get stuck. Would anyone mind telling me how to obtain $f'(a)$?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? What did you try? Hint: $f(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{f(x)}}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{0+y}}\implies y^2=x+\sqrt y\implies 16=y(a)^2=a+\sqrt4\implies a=14$$

and since we have that $\; y^4-2xy^2+x^2=y\;$ , differentiating impliclty we get

$$4y^3dy-4xydy-2y^2dx+2xdx=dy\implies$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\frac{y^2-x}{4y^3-2xy-1}$$

Now just substitute...

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{f(x)}}\\
(f(x))^2 = x + (f(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Differentiate (using the chain rule heavily) W.R.T $x$:

$$2f(x)f'(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(f(x))^{-\frac{1}{2}}f'(x)$$

or specifically at $x = a$,

$$2f(a)f'(a) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(f(a))^{-\frac{1}{2}}f'(a)$$

But $f(a) = 4$, so

$$2(4)f'(a) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}f'(a)\\
f'(a) = \frac{4}{31}$$